# Magento if buy some amount and then get one product free from our collection of product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

If i buy some products and total is more then 1000 then i will offer 1-product free from my selected products of different category, how can i do this in Magento.

Anybody having idea ?, tutorial link also nice help to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by creating shopping cart price rules through admin panel. In Admin panel, you can see Promotions in the menu and under to that shopping cart prices rules. In that create a New Rule and in that new rule, there is a condition field. Here you can give the Condition as shown in th following screenshots.

[image]

And in the next action field, make as below.

[image]

Thats it. Now if you add both the products to the cart, u can see the difference. In the above condition logic is only for your reference. You can add some more logic to that If you requires. Here is the link if you require... http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them